# Will dropping a database on the slave affect replication

Tags: mysql, replication

My replication crashed because a server IP Address of the slave server was mistakenly changed. Now the relay-bin files have used up all the space in the server, I cannot open the mysql server. Will dropping a database by deleting the .MYD, .MYI, .frm files affect replication when it starts?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you should definitly NOT start deleting files. My typical approach to this problem (it happens more often than one should think) is to move something (most often a biggish DB) to another disk, then link it back.

It is important, that you check and double-check your permissions, this includes `AppArmor` and `SELinux` profiles: For both, a link will not be the same as a directory.

Comment: Whatever little space you create these files quickly gobble it up.

Comment: What do you mean by "gobble it up" - which process does so? Do you mean, you keep MySQL running? NAGI!